# How Can I increase my timeout time in docker?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am having a problem with my docker machine. I need to increase the timeout time, but I don't know where. I increased the timeout in `php.ini` file, but doesn't work.

I need help, Thanks!

P.D.: My OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: timeout of what? can you elaborate, please, what are you actually running?

Comment: I am triying to process a render template but is too big and docker dont render the template in 30 seconds so i want increase the time. @vitr

Comment: have you logged in inside the container which is running php?

Comment: Yes @vitr I did. i am asking about some variable in docker-compose.yml whose function is give more time to timeout

Comment: well, could be a webserver timeout, what server do you use inside the container? very curious case, I never heard about timeout in compose...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change timeout value in your `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`:

```
max_execution_time = 3000000
```